# Java division not working when quotient is smaller than 1

Tags: java

I was coding today, when I occurred this problem.

```
System.out.println(block.chance); // -> 10
float chanceFloat = block.chance / 100;
System.out.println(chanceFloat); // -> 0.0
```

I'm not sure what is the problem.

Comment: I guess `block.chance` is an `int`. If so, I'd suggest you read [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Comment: Let me guess: `block.chance` is an integer? try `float chanceFloat = block.chance / 100f;`

Answer (score 1):

You are not stupid, you just are not aware of the language rules.

`block.chance` seems to be an integer, and the result of a division of two integers is an integer, even if it is assigned to a `float` cariable afterwards (then it is too late).

Your solution would be to use one of

```
float chanceFloat = block.chance / 100.0;
float chanceFloat = block.chance / 100.0f;
float chanceFloat = block.chance / 100.f;
float chanceFloat = block.chance / 100f;
float chanceFloat = (float)block.chance / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `block.chance` is an integer, then `block.chance/100` will be performed as integer division (i.e., the result is truncated), and then cast to a float.

If `block.chance` is positive and less than 100, this will always be 0.

The simplest fix is to ensure that the divisions requires floating point numbers by changing the type of at least one side of the division. The common idiom would be

```
float result = block.chance / 100.0;
```